# Bash Error while calling ARM template in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, shell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines

I am trying to do an ARM deployment using bash but getting this error

```
ArgumentUsageError: argument --template-uri/-u: expected one argument
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Pay-As-You-Go'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      armTemplateURI=$('https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/temp/Function-Deployment.json?'$(SASTOKEN))
      packageURI=$('https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/fileupload/PrdFunctions.zip?'$(SASTOKEN))
      output=$(az deployment group create --name "Function-Deployment" --resource-group "rg-dev-xxxx" --template-uri $armTemplateURI --parameters appName="fapp-dev-xxxx" storageName="stgdevxxxx" location="Australia East" cosmosName="cosmos-xxxx" msdeployPackageUrl=$packageURI)
```

Comment: Are there supposed to be ```<br/>```?

Comment: There is most like a space somewhere in `$armTemplateURI`, try building this variable in another task then printing it out to the console to narrow down the issue.

Comment: You can try to change the commands like this `armTemplateURI='https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/temp/Function-Deployment.json?'$SASTOKEN`.

Comment: Hi Charles, Thanks it worked. just wondering why my variable did not work? I'll try Matt's suggestion. Thank you all once again.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the document [Set secret variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) shows the way to set the secret in a secure way. And in bash, you do not need to use the `$()` to set a string as the value of a variable. So the right way for you should like this:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'Pay-As-You-Go'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
            armTemplateURI='https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/temp/Function-Deployment.json?'$MY_SASTOKEN
            packageURI='https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/fileupload/PrdFunctions.zip?'$MY_SASTOKEN
            output=$(az deployment group create --name "Function-Deployment" --resource-group "rg-dev-xxxx" --template-uri $armTemplateURI --parameters appName="fapp-dev-xxxx" storageName="stgdevxxxx" location="Australia East" cosmosName="cosmos-xxxx" msdeployPackageUrl=$packageURI)
        env: 
            MY_SASTOKEN: $(SASTOKEN)
```